# error: expected expression before ',' token

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

    struct nodes
    {
        char* info;
        struct nodes * left;
        struct nodes * right;

    };

    char* question = "any question?";
    struct nodes * node = NULL;
    struct nodes * nodeleft = NULL;
    struct nodes * noderight = NULL;

    struct nodes newNode (char info[50], struct nodes * l, struct nodes * r)        `       {
        struct nodes conf;
        conf.info = info;
        conf.left = l;
        conf.right = r;
        return conf;
    }
```

Here Im trying to create a new root node with null left and right nodes

```
    int main(){
        node = newNode (question, nodoleft*, nodoright*);

        return 0;
    }
```

dont know why i'm getting this error while Im trying to create a new node... I'm new in C
    error: error: expected expression before ',' token

Comment: `nodoleft*, nodoright*);`...hmmmmm

Comment: Sorry is nodeleft*, noderight* but it keeps getting the same error

Comment: in main, node is of type `struct nodes*` but newNode returns a `struct nodes`.

Comment: @JohanOZ : nodo isn't the only problem there, the * suffix is also incorrect.

Comment: There is a reason there is normally no space written in the declarator between the `*` and the variable name. Because that ressembles the usage pattern when dereferencing a pointer.

Comment: How about `node = newNode (question, nodeleft, noderight);`?

Comment: Your parameter declaration `char info[50]` is exactly equivalent to `char *info`; the `50` is quietly ignored. (This applies only to parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

In `"nodoleft*,"` and `"nodoright*"` it looks as though you have started a multiplication, and then left off without a second operand.  In any case, each parameter should be an expression. In this context, variable names do qualify as expressions. So, if you just have

```
node = newNode (question, nodeleft, noderight);
```

your compiler will probably be much happier.

Comment: It does not fix the fact that there is no permanent storage allocated for node.

Comment: @stark True. My intent was to address OP's question only.